# To create the files under a project in eclipse using Linux terminal

Tags: linux, eclipse, automation

I am not sure if it's possible or not but I'm trying to automate the creation of some `.txt` files under a specific project's folder in eclipse using Linux terminal or preferably using a shell script.

Would be helpful for any leads.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use _Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations..._ to run a shell script from within Eclipse and pass variables like e.g. `${selected_resource_path}` for the path of the current selected file to that script. Or what's your question?

Comment: @howlger: Actually, I've a shell script which contains the commands to create some txt files. I want to run this script from Linux terminal and would want this script to create the txt files under a specific project's folder in eclipse.

Comment: So you might use an _External Tool_ configuration or open the _Terminal_ view e.g. via right-click and _Show In > Terminal_ at a specific project location.

Comment: Thank You @howlger! I'll check this solution...would be great if you've any helpful link/url related to _External Tool configuration_ in eclipse...

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-97_standalone_ets.htm